# flutter CustomScrollView It scrolls even if the height isn't full enough

Tags: flutter, customscrollview

I am trying to use CustomScrollView to create a view whose height scrolls according to the content inside.

But with CustomScrollView, it scrolls even if its height is not full enough.

Is there any way to solve this?

here is my code

```
CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      faqInfo.title,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: titleTextStyle,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${faqInfo.lastEditTime.year}년 ${faqInfo.lastEditTime.month}월 ${faqInfo.lastEditTime.day}일'
                      '${'${faqInfo.lastEditTime.year}'.padLeft(2, '0')}:${'${faqInfo.lastEditTime.year}'.padLeft(2, '0')}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: normalSize,
                        color: lightTextColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 1,
                      color: lightGrayColor,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you can simply add **physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),** in CustomScrollView

CustomScrollView(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      slivers: [
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  faqInfo.title,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: titleTextStyle,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  '${faqInfo.lastEditTime.year}년 ${faqInfo.lastEditTime.month}월 ${faqInfo.lastEditTime.day}일'
                  '${'${faqInfo.lastEditTime.year}'.padLeft(2, '0')}:${'${faqInfo.lastEditTime.year}'.padLeft(2, '0')}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: normalSize,
                    color: lightTextColor,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 1,
                  color: lightGrayColor,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```